# How to use the secret file in a Jenkins Non Pipeline Jobs

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have a defined a secret file `ansible` in the global credentials and uploaded the private key `.pem` file. The credentials is available to all the nodes in the system. Then I used the credentials parameter in the Jenkins job as you can see below.

[image]

In the bindings section of the job I have referred to the `keyfile` as you can see below:

[image]

Problem is when I refer to this `keyfile` in the execute shell it should refer to my private key file but that's not happening :(

```
echo ${keyfile}

ssh -i "${keyfile}" ec2-user@server
```

and I am getting the error.

```
Warning: Identity file ansible not accessible: No such file or directory.
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Host key verification failed.
```

Any ideas what's going on here ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you cannot use global credentials in non-pipeline jobs in Jenkins.

Comment: Twould seem according to documentation that you can do this outside of jobs of type "pipeline" https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding/ https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-secure-guide/injecting-secrets BUT I am having the same issue now.... so maybe I'll just wrap it all up in a pipeline because wrappers are fun!